# disable right click in login page extjs not working

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd

I want to disable right click on a login page in extjs to prevent pasting of credentials. No matter whatever i tried, it is not working. Any suggestions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to listen to contextmenu on the body

```
       Ext.getBody().on('contextmenu', function(e) {e.preventDefault();});
```

Remember to clear the listener, once you need it no longer.